# Passing parameters error

Tags: python, parameters, nameerror

I am trying to create a program and get user data then pass it on to another function, but I keep getting a NameError, even though I (appear) to be passing the parameters properly and calling the function with that parameter too.

here is an example of my code:

```
#Define prompt to get player name
def welcomePrompt():
    print("Welcome to my beachy adventure game!")
    name=(input("Before we start, you must check-in, what is your name?:"))
    return name


#Define dictionary to access all player data
def dataDict(name):
    name=name
    print(name)


def main():
    welcomePrompt()
    dataDict(name)

main()
```

could someone please help? thanks

Comment: you forgot to close the string in `print("Welcome to my beachy adventure game!)`, add a quote

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the `name` value returned from `welcomePrompt()`; a local variable in a function is not going to be visible in another function, so the only way to pass on the result is by returning and then *storing that result*:

```
def main():
    name = welcomePrompt()
    dataDict(name)
```

Note the `name =` part I added. This is a *new local variable*. It may have the same name as the one in `welcomePrompt()`, but because it is a different function, the two are independent. You can rename that variable in `main()` to something else and not change the function of the program:

```
def main():
    result = welcomePrompt()
    dataDict(result)
```

Comment: so there is no way for me to use input from another function in another function?

Comment: @liverr1818: there is; you pass it around explicitly.